# How to resolve a "Whitelabel Error Page" in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, h2-console

I have made a "Pets" application using Model View Controller (MVC) Design Pattern in Gradle, with Spring Boot 3 framework, Thymeleaf template engine, in-memory H2 database with JPA, and Post-Redirect-Get design pattern. The program imitates a simple data-driven application to enter, display, edit, and delete pet data.

I have made Controller, Model, Repository, Service packages and inside that, I have made appropriate code. But I am receiving an error of:

> Whitelabel page - This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Here's my code:

PetController.java

```
package com.muskan.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import com.muskan.model.Pet;
import com.muskan.service.PetService;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/pets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public class PetController {
    private final PetService petService;

    @Autowired
    public PetController(PetService petService) {
        this.petService = petService;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String getAllPets(Model model) {
        List<Pet> pets = petService.getAllPets();
        model.addAttribute("pets", pets);
        return "pets/list";
    }

    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String showPetForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("pet", new Pet());
        return "pets/form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/new")
    public String savePet(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "pets/form";
        }

        petService.savePet(pet);
        return "redirect:/pets";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
    public String showEditPetForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        Pet pet = petService.getPetById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid pet ID: " + id));
        model.addAttribute("pet", pet);
        return "pets/form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/{id}/edit")
    public String updatePet(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet,
                            BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "pets/form";
        }

        pet.setId(id);
        petService.savePet(pet);
        return "redirect:/pets";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/delete")
    public String deletePet(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        petService.deletePet(id);
        return "redirect:/pets";
    }
}
```

Application Properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:petsdb
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

`Pet Model`

```
package com.muskan.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pets")
public class Pet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PetKind kind = PetKind.DOG;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PetSex sex = PetSex.FEMALE;

    private boolean vaccinated;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Inside Resources/templates -> I have made pets directory and inside that I have made list.html and form.html

Here is what I have tried:

- I tried changing directories of HTML files by putting it directly to the templates folder which didn't worked.
- I gave Request Mapping some parameters like this @RequestMapping(value = "/pets", method = RequestMethod.GET) but it didnt worked as well.
- I have also tried @ComponentScan inside Controller but didn't worked as well.

I am expecting to display the list.html on http://localhost:8080/pets

Comment: Please add `@ComponentScan(scanBasePackages=package_where_controller_is_defined)` , add this annotation where @SpringBootApplication exists

Comment: This usually happens when your controller class is in a different package other than where Main spring boot application class is